# Vor + Dative usage for action towards something

Tags: preposition, grammatical-case

From [this link](https://www.thoughtco.com/german-prepositions-and-the-accusative-case-4065315) and [this link](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Praeposition/Kasus/2Kasus.html#Anchor-vor-6873), I learnt that two-way prepositions are followed by *Akkusativ* when the situation involves action towards something.

Then I came across this sentence on a college website:

> Bitte gehen Sie vor der Anmeldung in die Beratung im X.

Since this sentence involves motion towards a place, why are they using *vor + Dativ?*

Comment: `Vor` doesn't refer to a place/location. It is used to indicate time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Vor" is temporal here:

> Please go to the consultancy in X before signing up.

Answer (score 4):

As the others have already said: "vor" is temporal here, which means it takes the dative.

Look at your sentence again. The motion expressed in it is not towards the "Anmeldung" but towards/into "Beratung". So "vor" obviously isn't involved in the motion - it belongs to the phrase telling you when to perform this motion: "vor der Anmeldung".

Incidentally, the temporal and local senses of "vor" are not that different:

indicating movement, it takes *Akkusativ*
indicating a point in space, it takes *Dativ*
indicating a point in time, it takes *Dativ*
[Except when you're "moving" a date *to* a certain point in time <sup>as Emanuel correctly points out</sup>]

Comment: Careful... "Ich lege mir meinen Urlaub vor die Feiertage". It's a point in time, yet done with accusative.